# Elastic beanstalk undocumented venv path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk containers have theis python venv located at **"/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest"**

But what does **"LQM1lest"** even mean? Not a singe documentation page mentions it.

Is there way to get it programmatically? Because its really looks like random string and a subject of change, i dont like the idea of hardcoding it in deploy scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python path env should be available through `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

You can also `source` it and `export` manually if you want (as root):

```
source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: my instance through aws eb, doesn't seem to have PYTHONPATH in it. any idea about it ?